# Java: File lastmodified itimestamp in aix

Tags: java, file

I want to sort the files in directory as oldest first in java to perform some opertion on files in (FIFO principle). 
For this i am using lastmodified method on each flie object and then comapring them through a comparator which gives me the sorted list like below

```
    public static ArrayList<File> sortListAscending(ArrayList<File> list) {
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<File>() {
        public int compare(final File o1, final File o2) {
            return new Long(((File) o1).lastModified()).compareTo(new Long(
                    ((File) o2).lastModified()));
        }
    });
    return list;
}
```

When i run this on windows i get a 13 digit timestamp returned , while in unix timestamp is not upto milliseconds .
So the above method fails in unix for the files which came in directory in that one second time frame.

Please suggest some work around ?

Comment: You need to use some additional information such as the filename or the original position in the directory.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for response , so as suggested by you to include filename so am i supposed follow a particular pattern in filename for eg alphabetical order and check that order also?

Comment: Yes, if there are details in the filename which are not recorded in the second based timestamp.

Comment: Thanks Peter i think this only seems to be a final workaround. being a newbie to aix i am still confused that if system does not store last modified timestamp upto millisecond then how come ls -lt is producing a valid result.

Comment: It is likely that it preserves the order in the directory if the timestamps are the same (another one of my suggestions ;) If you add files to a directory, they are likely to appear in the order you added them which can look about right.

Comment: Yes may be:-) Well thanks will try with your given solutions .

Answer (score 0):

On my `Ubuntu` machine timestamp is returned in `13` digit ie. Miliseconds. can you check if system clock is set correctly on your linux machine.

So you can apply comparison in seconds.

```
long lastModified1 = (o1.lastModified()/1000)
long lastModified2 = (o2.lastModified()/1000)

return Long.valueOf(lastModified1).compareTo(lastModified2);
```

Comment: Hi amit , timestamp returned in aix is also of 13 digit but the last 3 digits are always 0 for every file . Can u make sure that file modified timestamp has valid miliseconds values in your case ?

Comment: So you can ignore comparison in ms by rounding it.

Comment: Method which i used is still good with comapring seconds so i am worried about the files for same seconds only . :-)